# Programmatically deduce the size of an enum independently of the value of its elements?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Is there *any* way, possibly requiring C++11/14, to deduce the number of elements in an enum regardless of the values of the enum elements themselves?

Consider an enum like

`enum { Val1 = 1, Val2 = 2, Val3 = 4 }`

for which the answer would be 3. I know there's that wrinkle, where I could have e.g. `Val3 = Val1`, but this can be ignored for my use case.

I've seen quite a few similar questions, both here on SO and elsewhere, but I've yet to find a proper answer for this. If there is any at all.

Usually, the proposed solution is to introduce a LAST element, but this would only give me the next higher enum value (using the example above, that would be 5), which would be of no use to me.

Comment: NO. That is not possible even in **C++17**. For such features, compile-time reflection/introspection is required. Until we have that in the *core* language, wait.

Comment: What Nawaz said. The best you can do today is to obtain the underlying type, and thus get a very imprecise upper bound.

Comment: Wow! That was quick, guys. :-) Yeah, I was afraid this wouldn't be possible, but I thought I'd ask the knowledgable people here anyway.

Comment: Some libraries (as [better-enums](https://github.com/aantron/better-enums)) use MACRO to declare/define enum and then can provide some reflection on the custom enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If there is any at all.

There is *not*.

Even with the new C++17, there is not a proposal that I am aware of that would allow you to achieve this.

> Usually, the proposed solution is to introduce a LAST element, but this would only give me the next higher enum value (using the example above, that would be 5), which would be of no use to me.

Then you will have to re-aproach your problem.